# Matrix exponentiation using fermat's theorem

Tags: algorithm, matrix, numbers, exponentiation

Like we use fermat's little theorem for modular exponentiation , I was just wondering that is there any such method for fast matrix exponentiation ? Can we use fermat's theorem for matrix exponentiation ? If no then is there any faster method than divide and conquer method of exponentiation ?

Comment: actually this is a fine programming algorithm question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look for [Octave's implementation of that](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Functions-of-a-Matrix.html#Functions-of-a-Matrix). There it gives you some references. Here some links:

- http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1020098
- http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf

Comment: I think you misunderstood, OP is not asking about calculating `exp(M)`, but about calculating `M^e` modulo some integer.

Comment: As DanielFischer points out, exp(M) would seem to be not too useful in context of a modular result.

Comment: actually, it is part of the straightforward method in [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), but yes, I misunderstood it. :p