# Is there any fast method of matrix exponentiation?

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

Is there any faster method of matrix exponentiation to calculate M<sup>n</sup> (where M is a matrix and n is an integer) than the simple divide and conquer algorithm?

Comment: Hey i found one link in stackoverflow only check it out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268516/matrix-exponentiation-using-fermats-theorem

Comment: Expokit is a well known package for performing matrix exponentiations.  http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Expokit

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could factor the matrix into eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  Then you get

```
M = V * D * V^-1
```

Where V is the eigenvector matrix and D is a diagonal matrix.  To raise this to the Nth power, you get something like:

```
M^n = (V * D * V^-1) * (V * D * V^-1) * ... * (V * D * V^-1)
    = V * D^n * V^-1
```

Because all the V and V^-1 terms cancel.

Since D is diagonal, you just have to raise a bunch of (real) numbers to the nth power, rather than full matrices.  You can do that in logarithmic time in n.

Calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors is r^3 (where r is the number of rows/columns of M).  Depending on the relative sizes of r and n, this might be faster or not.

Comment: As far as i know this method has the same complexity as Exponentiation by Squaring. So is there any faster method ?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja: this is faster then exponentiation by squaring.  This is O(r^3) time, exponentiation by squaring is O(r^3 logn) time.

Comment: for a better explanation of the method mentioned above http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=pdf%20nth%20power%20of%20matrix&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.qc.edu.hk%2Fmath%2FTeaching_Learning%2FNth%2520power%2520of%2520a%2520square%2520matrix.pdf&ei=Jf9JULrwFsi8rAejh4C4DQ&usg=AFQjCNE7yqQce5jdtyyVLFpSZmYUnoWyVA

Comment: Very nice solution of the problem. Thanks a lot! I will use it in future!

Comment: Isn't it necessary for the matrix to be symmetric/hermitian in order to be decomposed into eigenvectors?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem

Comment: Not necessary, sufficient.

Comment: But this isn't a general solution since spectral decomposition isn't possible for defective matrices.

Comment: Unfortunately, solving the characteristic equation itself will take logarithmic time because you'll need to binary search, so speed increase is negligible.

Comment: @SinByCos yes, but isn't it logarithmic in the size of the matrix? Squaring is logarithmic in the exponent, so you can't really compare the two.

Comment: You can always find the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Jordan_normal_form) even for defective matrices. Then, D is not diagonal but the sum of a diagonal and a nilpotent matrix which you can still use very efficiently.

Comment: @WorldSEnder: Unfortunately the Jordan normal form is not numerically stable (the normal form is a discontinuous function of the matrix), so small rounding errors in computing the matrix can lead to large errors in the result.

Answer (score 8):

It's quite simple to use Euler fast power algorith. Use next algorith.

```
#define SIZE 10

//It's simple E matrix
// 1 0 ... 0
// 0 1 ... 0
// ....
// 0 0 ... 1
void one(long a[SIZE][SIZE])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            a[i][j] = (i == j);
}

//Multiply matrix a to matrix b and print result into a
void mul(long a[SIZE][SIZE], long b[SIZE][SIZE])
{
    long res[SIZE][SIZE] = {{0}};

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
            {
                res[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            a[i][j] = res[i][j];
}

//Caluclate a^n and print result into matrix res
void pow(long a[SIZE][SIZE], long n, long res[SIZE][SIZE])
{
    one(res);

    while (n > 0) {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            mul(a, a);
            n /= 2;
        }
        else {
            mul(res, a);
            n--;
        }
    }
}
```

Below please find equivalent for numbers:

```
long power(long num, long pow)
{
    if (pow == 0) return 1;
    if (pow % 2 == 0)
        return power(num*num, pow / 2);
    else
        return power(num, pow - 1) * num;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is frequently used to get high powers of matrices.

Comment: i know this method but need to speed it up further.

Comment: You'd better add this algorithm name into the question to avoid similar answers :)

Comment: Faster algorithm are much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend approach used to calculate Fibbonacci sequence in [matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form). AFAIK, its efficiency is O(log(n)).

Comment: You have to multiply that by the cost of multiplying matrices. The overall running time is O (n^3 log n).