# Compute sum of power of large sparse matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Given a query vector (one-hot-vector) `q` with size of `50000x1` and a large sparse matrix `A` with size of `50000 x 50000` and nnz of `A` is `0.3` billion, I want to compute `r=(A + A^2 + ... + A^S)q` (usually `4 <= S <=6`).

I can above equation iteratively using loop

```py
r = np.zeros((50000,1))
for i in range(S):
   q = A.dot(q)
   r += q
```

but I want to more fast method.

First thought was `A` can be symmetric, so [eigen decomposition would help for compute power of `A`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311869/is-there-any-fast-method-of-matrix-exponentiation). But since `A` is large sparse matrix, decomposition makes dense matrix with same size as `A` which leads to performance degradation (in aspect of memory and speed).

Low Rank Approximation was also considered. But `A` is large and sparse, so not sure which rank `r` is appropriate.

It is totally fine to pre-compute something, like `A + A^2 + ... + A^S = B`. But I hope last computation will be fast: compute `Bq` less than 40ms.

Is there any reference or paper or tricks for that?

Comment: Any feedback? please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the matrix is not sparse this the iterative method is the way to go.

Multiplying A.dot(q) has complexity O(N^2), while computing A.dot(A^i) has complexity O(N^3).

The fact that q is sparse (indeed much more sparse than A) may help.
For the first iteration `A*q` can be computed as `A[q_hot_index,:].T`.

For the second iteration the expected density of `A @ q` has the same expected density as A for A (about 10%) so it is still good to do it sparsely.

For the third iteration afterwards the `A^i @ q` will be dense.

Since you are accumulating the result it is good that your `r` is not sparse, it prevents index manipulation.
There are [several](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#sparse-matrix-classes) different ways to store sparse matrices. I myself can't say I understand in depth all of them, but I think [csr_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy-sparse-csr-matrix), [csc_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy-sparse-csc-matrix), are the most compact for generic sparse matrices.

Eigen decomposition is good when you need to compute a `P(A)`, to compute a `P(A)*q` the eigen decomposition becomes advantageous only when `P(A)` has degree of the order of the size of `A`. Eigen-decomposition has complexity `O(N^3)`, a matrix-vector product has complexity `O(N^2)`, the evaluation of a polynomial `P(A)` of degree `D` using the eigen decomposition can be achieved in `O(N^3 + N*D)`.

**Edit:** Answering questionss on the comments

1. "it prevents index manipulation" <- Could you elaborate this?

Suppose you have a sparse matrix `[0,0,0,2,0,7,0]`. This could be described as `((3,2), (5,7))`. Now suppose you assigne 1 to one element and it becomes `[0,0,0,2,1,7,0]`, it is now represented as `((3,2), (4,1), (5,7))`. The assignment is performed by insertion in an array, and inserting in an array has complexity `O(nnz)`, where nnz is the number of nonzero elements. If you have a dense matrix you can always modify one element with complexity `O(1)`.

2. What is the N in the complexity?

It is the number of rows, or columns, of the matrix `A`

3. About the eigen decomposition, do you want to say that it is worth
   that computing r can be achieved in O(N^3 +N*D) not O(N^3 + N^2)

Computing `P(A)` will have complexity `O(N^3 * D)` (with a different constant), for big matrices, computing `P(A)` using the eigen decomposition is probably the most efficient. But `P(A)x` have `O(N^2 * D)` complexity, so it is probably not a good idea to compute `P(A)x` with eigen decomposition unless you have big `D` `(>N)`, when speed is concerned.

Comment: I have some questions based on your answer.    

1. "it prevents index manipulation" <- Could you elaborate this?

2. What is the `N` in the complexity?

3. About the eigen decomposition, do you want to say that it is worth that computing `r` can be achieved in `O(N^3 +N*D)` not `O(N^3 + N^2)` ?

Comment: Appended to the answer.